# clone object not working properly on a page with jquery code created with PHP script

Tags: php, jquery

```
<li style="padding: 5px; width: 150px; overflow: hidden; float: left; height: 202px;">
    <div class="title"> <a href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=68&amp;virtuemart_category_id=7">Castle Bounce House</a> </div>
    <div class="image"> <a href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=68&amp;virtuemart_category_id=7"> <img height="100" width="130" border="0" src="http://newsite.domain.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/castle_themed_bo_4f844059227b89_90x90.jpg"></a> </div>
    $949.00
    <div class="addtocart">
        <div class="addtocart-area">
            <form action="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=cart" class="product" method="post">
                <div class="addtocart-bar">
                    <label class="quantity_box" for="quantity68"> </label>
                    <span class="quantity-box">
                    <input type="text" value="1" name="quantity[]" class="quantity-input">
                    --&gt; </span> <span class="quantity-controls"> 
                    <!--<input type="button" class="quantity-controls quantity-plus" />
        <input type="button" class="quantity-controls quantity-minus" />--> 
                    </span> <span class="addtocart-button">
                    <input type="submit" value=" " class="addtocart-button" name="addtocart">
                    </span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" value="Castle Bounce House" class="pname">
                <input type="hidden" value="com_virtuemart" name="option">
                <input type="hidden" value="cart" name="view">
                <noscript>
                &lt;input type="hidden" name="task" value="add" /&gt;
                </noscript>
                <input type="hidden" value="68" name="virtuemart_product_id[]">
                <input type="hidden" value="7" name="virtuemart_category_id[]">
            </form>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

i have this 'li' tag  and  it's cloning properly i have matched every line but their is submit button in both original and clone object and when i submitting my page through the original then it is working properly.But when i submitting my page through the clone then their functionality is not working properly can any one tell me what is the problem with the cloning in jquery.

this is my clone object :

```
<li style="padding: 5px; width: 150px; overflow: hidden; float: left; height: 202px;">
    <div class="title"> <a href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=68&amp;virtuemart_category_id=7">Castle Bounce House</a> </div>
    <div class="image"> <a href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=productdetails&amp;virtuemart_product_id=68&amp;virtuemart_category_id=7"> <img height="100" width="130" border="0" src="http://newsite.domain.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/castle_themed_bo_4f844059227b89_90x90.jpg"></a> </div>
    $949.00
    <div class="addtocart">
        <div class="addtocart-area">
            <form action="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=cart" class="product" method="post">
                <div class="addtocart-bar">
                    <label class="quantity_box" for="quantity68"> </label>
                    <span class="quantity-box">
                    <input type="text" value="1" name="quantity[]" class="quantity-input">
                    --&gt; </span> <span class="quantity-controls"> 
                    <!--<input type="button" class="quantity-controls quantity-plus" />
            <input type="button" class="quantity-controls quantity-minus" />--> 
                    </span> <span class="addtocart-button">
                    <input type="submit" value=" " class="addtocart-button" name="addtocart">
                    </span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" value="Castle Bounce House" class="pname">
                <input type="hidden" value="com_virtuemart" name="option">
                <input type="hidden" value="cart" name="view">
                <noscript>
                &lt;input type="hidden" name="task" value="add" /&gt;
                </noscript>
                <input type="hidden" value="68" name="virtuemart_product_id[]">
                <input type="hidden" value="7" name="virtuemart_category_id[]">
            </form>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: "not working properly". ah. the ever so useful diagnostic that explains oh-so-much. I'm going to say it's due to gamma rays and advise you to move your server to the bottom of a very deep mine shaft.

Comment: I don't even see a **single** PHP or JavaScript code.

Comment: sorry for using that line ...sir i want to say that when i submitting my page through the clone object then it's not working

Comment: @2 i have created the clone the second "li" tag through jquery as i mention

Comment: By the way, you seem to be passing `&amp;` in your URLs near the top of your code, when you should be passing `&` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had problems with

```
$elem.clone().function1().function2().bla().bla();
```

try

```
var $elemToClone = $elem.clone();
```

and

```
$elemToClone.function1().function2().bla().bla();
```

after.

Also share the js code.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that with [`.clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) (see the "true"?) the HTML code **and** all events are cloned. Also make sure not HTML ids are in the copied area, since only the last occurrence of the multiple same ids will be found.

I made once a hard search and replace on the cloned HTML string to replace the ids, and inserted it afterwards.

Comment: yes u r right......may be with the same name and id's on the page

Comment: sorry but I used name like   virtuemart_product_id[]